# How to retrieve data stored in the form of ArrayList on Firebase ANDROID Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a database management app. My Database Structure is :- [Under the Customer object I have added children having Arraylist Value. index zero  holds name, index 1,2 and 3 holds unique id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyK7G.png) , I am confused about how to read this data and put it in a customised listView. My code is`
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseReference details = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    details.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>() {};
           ArrayList<String> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}`
```

. App is crashing as soon as it is launched. Please help!!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: I got Solution to this problem. I am using  Object Data = dataSnapshot.getValue(); in ChildEventListener  to get database in type Object. And now, I can convert it into any type i want to use. Thanks  for showing interest to help me.